# Java compiler error - homework assignment

Tags: java, compiler-construction, instance

The compiler gives me the error "'void' type not allowed here...<= operator cannot be applied to java.lang.String,int...not a statement"

getHours() and getSeconds() return instance variables of type int. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 if (userCommand.equals("a")) {
            yourClock.advance();
            System.out.println(yourClock.getSeconds());
            System.out.println("The time is now" +
                    (yourClock.getHours()) <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
                    yourClock.getHours() +
                    (yourClock.getMinutes() <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
                    yourClock.getMinutes() +
                    (yourClock.getSeconds() <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
                    yourClock.getSeconds();
```

Comment: +1 for noting that it's homework. :)

Comment: We all started with homework or practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just look at this statement:

```
(yourClock.getHours()) <= 9 ? ".0" : ".")
```

Don't you think you are short of a '(' here?

It's better like this:

```
((yourClock.getHours() <= 9) ? ".0" : ".")
```

Answer (score 3):

You are closing your `println` in the wrong place.  You are closing it after the first getHours() call it should be

```
if (userCommand.equals("a")) {
            yourClock.advance();
            System.out.println(yourClock.getSeconds());
            System.out.println("The time is now" +
                    (yourClock.getHours() <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
                    yourClock.getHours() +
                    (yourClock.getMinutes() <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
                    yourClock.getMinutes() +
                    (yourClock.getSeconds() <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
                    yourClock.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are closing a printout too early

```
(yourClock.getHours()) <= 9 ? ".0" : ".") +
```

the closing ) after

```
getHours())
```

is closing your printout.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake, I need to read more carefully. Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: @MassStrike We've all been there.  Staring at code swearing it should work or compile and its a simple problem like a misplaced parenthesis or an == instead of !=. Sometimes it just takes fresh eyes.